# Nondegenerated algebraic set and global sections of twisted sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered the following argument in Eisenbud's geometry of syzygies (p75): [image]

I don't understand the part about the middle vertical map. How does $X$ being nondegenerate relates to the global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ and $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P}(1)$? Why is the map injective?

Comment: If $X$ is degenerate, by definition it lies in some hyperplane. The section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^r}(1)$ which cuts out that hyperplane then lies in the kernel of the restriction map.

Comment: @TabesBridges looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record that below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a nondegenerate scheme is not contained in any hyperplane. If we suppose that $X$ *is* contained in some hyperplane $H$, the equation of $H$ generates the kernel of the restriction map
$$
H^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^r}(1)) \to H^0(\mathcal O_X(1)),
$$

namely $H^0(\mathcal I_X(1))$. When $X$ is nondegenerate, each intersection $X \cap H$ is a subscheme of codimension $1$ in $X$, hence the zero locus of a non-zero section of $\mathcal O_X(1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I just keep forgetting the correspondence of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and the actual geometry.